# Vue + Typescript, Why is my computed property not updating my view

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I cannot figure out why my computed property is not updating my view, my computed property is supposed to calculate the combinedPrice() of my items but it's only giving me the initial price.

I have `<input type="number" min="1" v-model.number="count" />` multiplied with the item.price suppose to give me the combined price. I narrowed it down and I believe the bug comes from the input but cannot figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help me with this bug?

```html
<template>
  <main class="container">
    <section
      class="image"
      :style="`background: url(/${currentItem.img}) no-repeat center center`"
    ></section>

    <section class="details">
      <h1>{{ currentItem.item }}</h1>

      <h3>Price: ${{ currentItem.price.toFixed(2) }}</h3>

      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" min="1" v-model.number="count" />
        <button @click="addToCart" class="primary">
          Add to Cart - ${{ combinedPrice }}
        </button>
      </div>
      {{ combinedPrice }}
      <fieldset v-if="currentItem.options">
        <legend>
          <h3>Options</h3>
        </legend>
        <div v-for="option in currentItem.options" :key="option">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="option"
            :id="option"
            :value="option"
            v-model="itemOptions"
          />
          <label :for="option">{{ option }}</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset v-if="currentItem.addOns">
        <legend>
          <h3>Add Ons</h3>
        </legend>
        <div v-for="addon in currentItem.addOns" :key="addon">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="addon"
            :id="addon"
            :value="addon"
            v-model="itemAddons"
          />
          <label :for="addon">{{ addon }}</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <!-- <Toast v-if="cartSubmitted">
        Order Submited!<br />
        Check out more <nuxt-link to="/restaurants">restaurants</nuxt-link>
      </Toast> -->
    </section>

    <section class="options">
      <h3>Description</h3>
      <p>{{ currentItem.description }}</p>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import { Item } from "@/api/interfaces";

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    // let id: string = this.$route.params.id;
    // let count: number = 1;
    // let itemOptions: string = "";
    // let itemAddons: string[] = [];
    // let itemSizeAndCost: any[] = [];
    // let cartSubmitted: boolean = false;

    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      count: 1,
      itemOptions: "",
      itemAddons: [],
      itemSizeAndCost: [],
      cartSubmitted: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["foodData"]),
    currentItem(): Item {
      let result;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.foodData.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.foodData[i].menu.length; j++) {
          if (this.foodData[i].menu[j].id === this.id) {
            result = this.foodData[i].menu[j];
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    },
    combinedPrice(): number {
      let total = this.count * this.currentItem.price;
      return total;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

However, when I check Chrome Vue Extension I see the count and the combinedPrice being updated

[image]

Comment: try out to remove `break;`

Comment: What if you put a :key on details and update it when you choose a new product?

Answer (score 0):

It was freezing up because there was not a method to handle the button. the button method depended on the computed property. Once a method was added it worked just as expected.

```html
<button @click="addToCart" class="primary">
          Add to Cart - ${{ combinedPrice.toFixed(2) }}
        </button>
```

```html
 methods: {
    addToCart() {
      alert("add to cart button");
    },
  },
```